# Group policy access with active directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Under Active Directory (Win2008-R2), I want all "authenticated users" be able to access the "Add/Remove windows components" menu

But where do I have to go in group policy to set this grant ?

In

> User config. > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control Panel`

I don't see anything really "interesting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not there, because it's not an option.  Certain actions (like adding and removing Windows components) require administrative rights, so you'll have to give `Authenticated Users` administrative rights on all machines you want them to be able to do that on.  Not a good idea, for obvious reasons.

The better approach is to use GPOs, configuration management, and/or an imaging solution to control which Windows components are installed on what workstations in a more flexible fashion.